# What is the window.userContext and where is this loaded from?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

There are several JavaScript Global Variables offered by [Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&type=5).
I was trying to locate some documentation around window.userContext but could not find anywhere. We are trying to use the window.userContext.locale information to correctly show the numbers based on the User Locale. At present, I am trying to identify how the userContext is loaded and how can we manipulate this.

Comment: P.S. I suspect that this is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I suggest you ask a new question that details what you're trying to achieve, and let us help guide you to an appropriate solution. As I've outlined in my answer, whatever you're trying to do, this is not the correct way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks for the details, all we are doing is to correctly show the numbers based on the User Locale, and from how you have explained, I believe, Remote invocation is a way to go with Classic and Lightning.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce does not provide any generic "JavaScript global variables;" the page you've linked to are global *merge* variables, used in places like formulas and Visualforce. `window.UserContext`, and other variables created on `window`, are used to provide information about the user to the system's JavaScript library. Formally, this global variable appears to be defined in `/jslibrary/timestamp/sfdc/main.js` around line 255. It is also used by the AJAX Toolkit for additional information, like endpoint discovery. This variable does not exist in Lightning Experience or Communities, as far as I can tell.

You cannot depend on any JavaScript global variable from the system library existing or providing useful information. You should not attempt to do so. If you need the user's locale or other information, you should be merging it in from a database query, such as by using Visualforce Remoting, an API call, or some other mechanism. The exact details of how you get this data will depend on the context you're doing this in.